# How to logout an user(role) when an admin(role) is logged in Express Js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working in express js. For my login page i am using passport and connect roles. My query is, if an user(role) is logged in, at the same time an admin tries to login, the user should be automatically logged out and admin should be logged in. I tried to achieve using status for admin role. I want to acheive this in intranet connection. But it is only suitable for other scenarios. Can we use session to acheive this.

Comment: your question is not clear. you are stuck at some place ? or you want to know approach ? or you want to know the feasibility ?

Comment: @Aky both admin and user cannot be logged in same time in any system connected to intranet, once the admin logged in, the previously logged in user should be logged out automatically.

Comment: yes, you should use sessions. Remove other users session from the session store or mark it with a flag such that logic checks that and redirect normal user when next request comes in.